# Hyperlink in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

How I create hyperlink in J2ME?
After click the string item J2ME has to open website in system web browser.

Answer (score 1):

See the same [discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?149202-Hyperlink-inside-J2ME) on nokia forum. It will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Better create your own Button component by extending Item class and overriding paint to draw text with specified font and underlined and also you can add Action listener to it so that you can perform action
usable in forms too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Platformrequest method to launch link in webBrowser .
Just check string is valid web address or not.